# Picking The Right OpenCV Build For Windows

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to make heads and tails of the list of files available for Windows at OpenCV's website.

This is the list at SourceForge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3/) for v2.3:

- OpenCV-2.3.0rc-gpu-support-win32-vs2008.zip
- OpenCV-2.3.0rc-win64-vs2010.exe
- OpenCV-2.3.0rc-win32-vs2008.exe
- OpenCV-2.3.0rc-win-src.zip

I've deduced the following so far:

- OpenCV-2.3.0rc-gpu-support-win32-vs2008.zip: The only way to get support for using GPUs.
- OpenCV-2.3.0rc-win64-vs2010.exe: Used if you are using Visual Studio 2010 and 64-bit Windows
- OpenCV-2.3.0rc-win32-vs2008.exe: Used if you are using VS 2008 and 32-bit Windows
- OpenCV-2.3.0rc-win-src.zip: Source code for OpenCV on Windows (but might not support GPUs).

I'm left with the following questions (assuming that I don't want to compile from the source code):

- Which version should I pick if want to use Visual Studio 2008, OpenCV, and a 64-bit version of Windows?
- Which version should I pick for Visual Studio 2010, OpenCV, and 32-bit Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice the filenames they contain the letters **rc** which stand for *release candidate*. I would not recommend using this version just yet. **[Grab OpenCV 2.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.2/)** if you don't need specific features from the 2.3.

There's a [README](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-win/2.2/OpenCV-2.2.0-win-README.txt?r=http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.2/&ts=1309201029&use_mirror=ufpr) file on that page explaining what's inside each package. All v2.2 packages are 32-bit.

> Which version should I pick if want to use Visual Studio 2008, OpenCV, and a 64-bit version of Windows?

You will have to rebuild OpenCV from the sources. Download **OpenCV-2.2.0-win.zip** or **OpenCV-2.3.0rc-win-src.zip** for the 2.3 version.

> Which version should I pick for Visual Studio 2010, OpenCV, and 32-bit Windows?

For the 2.3 version, you will also have to rebuild OpenCV from the sources, **OpenCV-2.3.0rc-win-src.zip**. For the 2.2 version, there's the package **OpenCV-2.2.0-win32-vs2010.exe**, which includes OpenCV source code, documentation, samples and pre-compiled 32-bit binaries.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Since SF lists the RC next to "Looking for the latest version", I was tricked into thinking that 2.3 had been officially released or was like other projects with never-ending betas/RCs.